How to sort query result on a string field containing software version x.y.z
I am writing a web site using Django framework.
I have a model that stores software and its version number in the format "x.y.z" (or "x", "x.y"), where x, y, and z are integer numbers. How can I sort the query results by the version number in ascending order?
The default sorting behavior is based on string alphabet order, but not what I want.

Does this answer your question? Sorting release versions of the format YYYY.MM.DD in a Django queryset

I don't want to convert the query result to a list.

Have you tried using the raw SQL approach in this answer?

PostgreSQL has a SPLIT_PART function but Django currently doesn't support it. Fortunately you can write your own database functions, for example:
from django.db.models import Func


class SplitPart(Func):
    function = 'SPLIT_PART'
    template = "SPLIT_PART(%(expressions)s, '%(delimiter)s', %(pos)s)"

Then, you can do something like this:
from functools import partial
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


sorted_objects = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    v1=Cast(partial(SplitPart, delimiter=".", pos=1)("version"), output_field=IntegerField()),
    v2=Cast(partial(SplitPart, delimiter=".", pos=2)("version"), output_field=IntegerField()),
    v3=Cast(partial(SplitPart, delimiter=".", pos=3)("version"), output_field=IntegerField()),
).order_by("v1", "v2", "v3")


This splits the value of the version column using "." as a separator, Casts each part to an IntegerField, then orders the queryset by those parts.
Obviously you will have to extend this approach to support "x" and "x.y" formats.

Unfortunately, I am using sqlite3 . It looks like that the SplitPart can not be supported

No, in that case you will have to use a combination of SUBSTR and INSTR functions as in this answer. I will still leave the answer as it might help future visitors who use PostgreSQL. You can also try ordering them in Python.
